# If Expressions Don't Work

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having a problem with getting if expressions to work. The problem is that the first if statement is used, even if the expression beside should return a value of FALSE.

For example, when I run this script, it should be that `%X%` would have a value of 10 by the time it has run twice. (First is 5, second is 10). `%length%` would then incidentally have a value of 2 on the second run.

The message box that I get on the second run says "The length of InputVar is 2. - One - 2" all the way up through the 19th run which says "The length of InputVar is 2. - One - 19". Then when it hits runs 20 (through 22), it says "The length of InputVar is 3. - One - 20".

What am I doing wrong?

```
^1::
X:=0
Y:=0
Loop, 22
{
Y:=++Y
X:=5+X
InputVar:=X
StringLen, length, InputVar
if (%length%<2)
{
MsgBox, 1, Length, The length of InputVar is %length%. - One - %Y%, 2
}
else if (%length%==2)
{
MsgBox, 1, Length, The length of InputVar is %length%. - Two - %Y%, 2
}
else if (%length%>2)
{
MsgBox, 1, Length, The length of InputVar is %length%. - Three - %Y%, 2
}
else
{
MsgBox, 1, Length, The length of InputVar is %length%. - Unknown - %Y%, 2
}
Sleep 500
}
Return

;These are the written numbers I should expect to be paired up with %Y%.
;One - 1
;Two - 2-19
;Three - 20-22
```

Comment: I see no assignment to length, and Length (case sensitive) being used too. Could this be related?

Comment: I forgot to mention, and left it to be inferred, that %length% is being evaluated correctly when it is used in the Message Box command. So I'm not sure why the %length%<2 and ==2 and >2 is not working as determining which message to display.

Comment: Please, if you have an answer, post an answer - don't edit your question to say "solved".  This isn't a regular forum.  Folks know your question is "solved" when you mark an answer as accepted.  So, please fix your question back to being a question, and move your solution to a new answer - just scroll down to where it says, "Your answer" and post there.  Then you can accept the answer and get two points!

Answer (score 0):

I edited the original post. Check the first line.

> (Solved! I needed to get rid of the % in %length% when comparing it against the value of 2.)

Edit: And, BGM, did you know you have to wait a day to mark your own answer as the correct answer? I won't be back tomorrow :)