# Why MsgBox 1>2 alert 1>2 rather than false when using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing AutoHotkey script, and now confused about how to compare numbers in AutoHotkey. `1>2` is obviously false, but why the `MsgBox alerts 1>2` rather than false?

I think this is a boolean comparison, why msgbox don't calculate the result?

[image]

This problem is not the same as [If Expressions Don't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177057/if-expressions-dont-work/18196857#18196857) .

Comment: You forgot to accept some answer. As a non-poster on this question reminding you feels like a duty.

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely because your code looks like this: `MsgBox, (if(1>2))`

Which is read by AHK as: `Create a message-box, and use the message '(if(1>2))'`.

If you want to actually evaluate expressions and use the result as the message, the proper syntax is this: `MsgBox, % 1>2`

This would print out `0` in the message-box, which is equal to `false`, since in AHK the words `true` and `false` are just built-in variables containing `1` and `0`.

I suggest you read this page on [Variables and Expressions](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm) from the docs. They provide a good insight into how AHK handles variables and expressions, as it can be a bit... special.

Answer (score 2):

```
msgbox, % check(1 > 2)


return

check(now)
{
if (now)
return "true"
else
return "false"
}
```

using this function you can check the expression's result and return it to the msgbox!

look at the

```
%
```

that makes the msgbox show the RESULT of the expression and not the string its written as (ahk flaw in my opinion)